# Data driven forms for a web application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mustache

I have a web application where some fields will vary between tenants, e.g. some may have items that look like:

```
{
  "name": "John Smith",
  "age": 20
}
```

but another tenant might have their data with a shape like:

```
{
  "name": "John Smith",
  "age": 20,
  "preference": 1
}
```

Each tenant already defines the fields via a JSON schema, and this is validated. Data is rendered on the front-end using custom Mustache templates also specified per tenant.

However, I'd like to enable some custom form definitions that can be customized as needed. For example, for the 2nd tenant they may want the `preference` field to be a form input that resolves to `number`.

Another tenant may want the `preference` field to be set of radio buttons with predetermined choices.

Are there any existing data-driven form solutions out there that I could expose the form-templates and allow each tenant to edit their own bit of UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you need to create a form based on JSON schema with additional form fields using React.

You should check [React JSON Schema Form](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form)

This takes you JSON schema, a UI schema and your value and renders a form based on it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be with [Angular Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form)